# In consensus-by-bet, are all bets registered on the chain?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

From Vlad:

> Validators bet independently on blocks at every height (i.e. block number) by assigning it a probability and publishing it as a bet. Through iterative betting, the validators elect exactly one block at every height

Are all bets published on the chain, and if so, do they end up in the next block, or is the Casper smart contract prioritized in each block (so that a record of the betting always ends up in the block that is selected in consensus-by-bet) or how does that work?